# Function takes longer than expected to complete

Tags: javascript

I've created a simple sliding function that should make an element appear or disappear in the amount of time given.

My formula for building this function is: **`ms = 1 pixel / (initial size / duration)`**, essentially calculating how many milliseconds should pass before subtracting **`1px`** from the element's **`height`** or **`width`**.

My math logic says that the function should complete in **`1000ms`**, yet to me,  the time it takes to complete looks significantly more, without being sure how much.

Why does it take longer than **`1s`** to complete and what may be causing it?

**Code:**

```js
/* ----- JavaScript ----- */
function slide(el, duration, direction) {
  /* Default */
  duration = duration || 1000, direction = direction || "vertical";

  var
    dim = (direction === "horizontal") ? "width" : "height",
      
    /* Get how tall or wide el is in 'px' */
    size = initSize = parseFloat(
      getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue(dim) || el.style[dim]
    ),
      
    /* Get the previous size, so as to restore el to it */
    prevSize = el.style["prev" + dim] || 0,
      
    /* Calculating how many ms should pass before subtracting 1px*/
    ms = 1 / (initSize / duration),
      
    interval = setInterval(function() {
      /* If el is visible */
      if (initSize > prevSize && size > prevSize) el.style[dim] = --size + "px";
      
      /* If el is not visible */
      else if (prevSize > initSize && size <= prevSize) el.style[dim] = ++size + "px";
      
      /* Clear the interval when 0 is reached and cache the previous size */
      else {
        console.log("oops")
        el.style["prev" + dim] = initSize;
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
    }, ms);
}

slide(document.getElementById("a"));
```

```html
<!----- HTML ----->
<div id = "a" style = "width: 200px;height: 300px;background-color:black;"></div>
```

Comment: what is the value of `ms`? the smaller it is, the less accurate the timing will be - I'd be looking into `requestAnimationFrame` and refactor your code to subtract a certain number of pixels per animation frame - in other words, calculate the number of pixels to subtract depending on how much time has elapsed since the previous frame - ends up in smoother consistent animation

Comment: Your function doesn't *ever* complete: it never gets to the `clearInterval()`. Check your browser's console... Also, regarding your comment that "the time it takes to complete looks significantly more, without being sure how much", why don't you actually measure it with `console.log(Date.now())` before starting and at the point you call `clearInterval()`, or look into using [`console.time()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/time)...

Comment: @JaromandaX if we have an element with **`height: 300px`** and the duration we set is **`300ms`**, **`ms`** will equal to **`1`** *(1/ (300px / 300ms))*

Comment: @nnnnnn Sorry about that, it was just a typo in my snippet. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: setInterval & setTimeout with delay less than 10 ms generally is not that accurate and varies browser to browser. in your case it's about 3.33 ms that's why taking long, about 1.3 sec.

Comment: @SufianSaory you're right, I just did the test suggested by @nnnnnn and I got the same result. DO you have any idea how to handle this, since **`setInterval`** is inaccurate?

Comment: as I said before, change the code to change the number of pixels based on elapsed time

Comment: @JaromandaX check out [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39314177/6313073). I have taken your advice into consideration and used **`window.requestAnimationFrame`** which indeed is better. However, the sliding time still exceeds the duration provided, perhaps, because I have taken into account a static (60fps) frame rate. Is there a way to alleviate that?

Comment: of course - this can easily be done with CSS transformations - possibly with greater accuracy, possibly not, who's to say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some thoughts that reading Jaromanda X's comments made me have, I finally ended up using **`window.requestAnimationFrame()`**, as it's more efficient than **`setInterval()`** and it also doesn't force browser redraw.

This in turn made me change my formula from time-oriented (**`ms = 1 / (initial size / duration)`**) to pixel-oriented (**`px = frame * (initial size / duration)`**).

The sliding is smoother now and very close to **`1000ms`**, with only **`5-7ms`** difference which I believe occurs, because I have set the **`frame`** variable to **`1000 / 60`** not taking into consideration the frame rate drops that may occur.

**Code:**

```js
/* ----- JavaScript ----- */
function slide(el, duration, direction) {
  /* Set Defaults and record starting date */
  var a = Date.now();
  duration = duration || 1000, direction = direction || "vertical";

  var
    dim = (direction === "horizontal") ? "width" : "height",

    /* Get how tall or wide el is in 'px' */
    size = initSize = parseFloat(
      getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue(dim) || el.style[dim]
    ),

    /* Get the previous size, so as to restore el to it */
    prevSize = el.style["prev" + dim] || 0,

    /* Calculating how many px should be added / subtracted each frame */
    frame = 1000 / 60,
    px = frame * (initSize / duration),
    step = (initSize > prevSize) ? -px : px;

  window.requestAnimationFrame(function transform() {
    el.style[dim] = (size > 0) ? (size += step) + "px" : (size = 0);
    if (size === 0) {
      el.style["prev" + dim] = initSize;
      //element.style.prevDisplay = initDisplay;
      console.log(Date.now() - a)
    } else window.requestAnimationFrame(transform);
  }, frame);
}

slide(document.getElementById("a"), 1000);
```

```html
<!----- HTML ----->
<div id="a" style="width: 200px;height: 300px;background-color:black;"></div>
```

Comment: I'm getting times from 1984 to 2000 - which is an error of a single animation frame for some reason

Comment: sorry, tested your code with 2000 ;) ... with 1000 I get 984 to 1000

Comment: not sure how much more accurate you want it - I can think of better code though, which doesn't make any assumptions about the frame to frame accuracy of requestAnimationFrame - https://jsfiddle.net/ecu1y9j9/4/

Comment: I see now why I tested with 2000 - because you **originally had 2000 in your code snippet**

Comment: How better than the fiddle you provided @JaromandaX? Because ±5-10ms may not be much for a duration of 1000ms, but for 100ms it's a 10% increase.

Comment: here's the problem - browsers timer accuracy isn't atomic clock grade

Comment: hahaha, okay. Your code is fine with ±2ms difference, but you've changed my initial code a lot and I'm kind of lost :p

Comment: that's why I posted it as a fiddle, rather than an answer. basically, it figures out the total change, then on each frame it sees how far into the duration the time has gone (since start) and then calculates the pixel height based on the total time change. I also changed `style["prev" + dim]` to `dataset["prev" + dim]` because the style of an object is **not** the place to store data for an element - that's what the dataset is for :p ... though, it isn't **that** big a change from your code

Answer (score 1):

you need to adjust your step size i.e number of pixel to be added/removed per iteration and adjust the delay time. following is a improved version which takes about around 1.1 sec.

```
function slide(el, duration, direction) {
  /* Default */
  duration = duration || 1000, direction = direction || "vertical";

  var dim = (direction === "horizontal") ? "width" : "height",

    /* Get how tall or wide el is in 'px' */
    size = initSize = parseFloat(
      getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue(dim) || el.style[dim]
    ),

    /* Get the previous size, so as to restore el to it */
    prevSize = el.style["prev" + dim] || 0;

    /* Calculating how many ms should pass before subtracting 1px*/
    var step = 1;
     var ms = 1 / (initSize / duration)
    if(ms<10){
        ms=10;
        step = 10*(initSize/duration);
        console.log(ms,step)
    }
      var now=new Date();
      var interval;var i=0;
    var animate = function() {
    i++;
        interval=setTimeout(animate,ms);
      /* If el is visible */
      if (initSize > prevSize && size > prevSize) el.style[dim] = (size=size-step) + "px";

      /* If el is not visible */
      else if (prevSize > initSize && size <= prevSize) el.style[dim] = (size=size+step) + "px";

      /* Clear the interval when 0 is reached and cache the previous size */
      else {
        console.log("oops", new Date()-now,size,step,i)
        el.style["prev" + dim] = initSize;
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
    };
    //var interval = setInterval(animate, ms);
    animate();
}
slide(document.getElementById("a"));
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. It indeed reduces the sliding time to 1100ms, which is better than the one I had, so I upvoted :) After some researching I ended up changing my code to the one provided in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39314177/6313073) reducing it even more to an average of 1005ms.